# Prevent Keyboard from hiding the submit button of alert Dialog

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I have a custom Spinner class and which uses an alert Dialog to display its contents and it has "Submit" and "Cancel" buttons. The alert dialog has one edit text and others are just read-only labels. On click of edit text the virtual keyboard appears and it moves the layout moves bit up but the buttons remain hidden. I want the buttons to be visible also.

Things I have tried so far:-
Manifest :-
[image]android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize"
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"

In Activity Class:-
this.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN);

It is just moving screen enough not to hide the edit text where as my button are still remain invisible.

[image]

Comment: Can you show your xml code for AlertDialog contentView ?

Comment: @tahsinRupam I am just using the default alert dialog there is no xml file for that. And its been called inside a custom spinner class.

Comment: Add this in your Activity: `getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE);`  instead of `SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN`

Comment: @rafsanahmad007  it's not working.

Comment: `getWindow()` needs to be applied on alertdialog like: `alertDialog.getWindow()`...and in manifest: `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateHidden"`

Comment: @ rafsanahmad007 I have forgot to mention its an alert dialog builder. And getwindow() is not getting recognized,Sorry for that I primarily work in iOS and am new to android so is not bit aware of these details.

Answer (score 0):

You can't.  The height of the keyboard is decided by the keyboard-  it can't be made smaller.  The rules for the keyboard are that if it the cursor would be covered, unless all movement is shut off it will scroll everything the minimum such that the cursor is on screen.  There is no way to tell the OS to scroll it more than that.  There is resize, but I'm not sure that will work for an alert dialog-  I think those still go full screen.  The keyboard API just isn't made for your usecase.